# Using Where on a list which is contained in another list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Let's say I have a list called `list1`. This `list1` contains another list, called `list2`. Now I want to check if `list2` in `list1` contains certain elements and return another list.

```
list3 = list1.list2.Where(p => p.something == 1)
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will return conditioned items in the inner list.

```
var result = list.SelectMany(l => l.InnerList)
                 .Where(p => p.something == 1);
```

If you want to get items in the outer list which meets the condition, use:

```
var another = list.Where(l => l.InnerList.Any(p => p.something == 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) function.